# Javascript array filter based on 2nd level array key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter an array that has 2 levels of children. I am able to filter the 1st level of the array but not the 2nd. I am trying to return an array that has a specific `email` under `collaborators`. Here is the structure

[image]

and here is the code. This code does not match `email` so return all the items in the array

```
this.firebase.list('/todo').
map(data => data.filter((e) => {
    return e.collaborators.filter((x) => {
        return x.email == email;
    });
}));
```

Sample JSON:

```
{
  "todo" : {
    "-Kee7m7WkNDhrbX_0Ycb" : {
      "collaborators" : [ {
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "name" : "test"
      },
      {
        "email" : "test1@gmail.com",
        "name" : "test1"
      } ],
      "created_at" : 1488913112569,
      "created_by" : "test@gmail.com",
      "preview" : "",
      "title" : "test",
      "updated_at" : 1488913112569
    },
    "-Kee7m7WkNDhrbX_0Ycb" : {
      "collaborators" : [ {
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "name" : "test"
      },
      {
        "email" : "test2@gmail.com",
        "name" : "test2"
      } ],
      "created_at" : 1488913112569,
      "created_by" : "test@gmail.com",
      "preview" : "",
      "title" : "test",
      "updated_at" : 1488913112569
    }
  }
}
```

Required output:

Only the first array which has an email `test1@gmail.com`

Comment: Please provide data that can be cut and pasted rather than a screenshot of data

Comment: Please post not only the input but also the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your desired output but hope that the following example helps you.

Hope this helps.

```js
var obj = {
  "todo" : {
    "-Kee7m7WkNDhrbX_0Yca" : {
      "collaborators" : [ {
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "name" : "test"
      },
      {
        "email" : "test1@gmail.com",
        "name" : "test1"
      } ],
      "created_at" : 1488913112569,
      "created_by" : "test@gmail.com",
      "preview" : "",
      "title" : "test",
      "updated_at" : 1488913112569
    },
    "-Kee7m7WkNDhrbX_0Ycb" : {
      "collaborators" : [ {
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "name" : "test"
      },
      {
        "email" : "test2@gmail.com",
        "name" : "test2"
      } ],
      "created_at" : 1488913112569,
      "created_by" : "test@gmail.com",
      "preview" : "",
      "title" : "test",
      "updated_at" : 1488913112569
    }
  }
};

var email = "test1@gmail.com";
var result = [];

for(var key in obj["todo"]) {
   obj["todo"][key].collaborators.filter((x) => {
     if ( x.email == email )
       result.push( obj["todo"][key] );
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok please post your object.

Comment: I actually want the entire ` "-Kee7m7WkNDhrbX_0Ycb"` object when email matches `test1@gmail.com`. I actually see that x.email == email works. but the first filter for some reason return entire array list `todo`.

Comment: This works for me! I also got the same results with basic for loop

Answer (score 0):

You want the `filter` callback to return a boolean value, not an array. So use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of `filter` on the collaborators.